# Weird graphics in software center

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I just installed ubuntu 12.10, and everything is running great, except in the software center. I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 430, and whenever I go into the software center insted of seeing words there's just a black box. It will sometimes load correctly but everything will start flashing. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (i am on a Nvidia Geforce 550GTX TI)

run each 1 of these in terminal

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates;`

`sudo apt-get update;`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings;`

this should fix the problem :) it worked for me anyways

Answer (score 0):

Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  simultaneously to enter terminal.

**To uninstall Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get remove software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`

**To re-install Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install software-center`

Comment: Still a little glitchy sometimes, but much better. Thank you!

Comment: if it is enough please confirm answer